# ViewPager with Toolbar and TabLayout has wrong height

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I have a ViewPager below an AppBarLayout (with a Toolbar and a TabLayout). I cannot understand why the height of the loaded fragments is more than the available space, even if there are no elements so big, making the tab scrollable.

This is the main layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see in my Fragment I have a Button with a layout_alignParentBottom but I guess it's stretching the height of the viewpager too much.

[image: screenshot]

Here the layout from the design view:

[image]

Comment: Can you shoot screen your app?

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Yeah, sure. Added a screen.

Comment: @Enrichman did you find out the solution to your problem?Asking because i am facing the exact same issue. :(

Comment: @Droidwala nope, in the end I've changed slightly the design.. :(

Comment: Looks like that's the only option left..what design change you made then in your case?Moved logout somewhere else?

Comment: @Droidwala yes, exactly. I didn't finish the app because I'm working also on other project but the plan is to redesign it without the tabs!

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

you can try to add a LinearLayout between AppBarLayout and ViewPager. It works for me. :)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will have side effect of sticky action bar, will not hide on scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `padding` to the `ViewPager` did the trick for me:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Note that the padding has the exact same size as the toolbars `height`.
Instead of `?attr/actionBarSize`, `?actionBarSize` is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this.**

Here you need to declare **`android:fillViewport="false"`** property in `Tab Bar`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Do change here in `Tab Bar`.**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />
```

**EDIT 1:**

**This is what working for me Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Still the same. As you can see from the screenshot the logout button should be at the bottom, but the height of the fragment is more of the space available, and so all the view is scrollable. (I've added a screenshot from the design view)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a fixed toolbar without scrolling, then you can remove `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` from the layout design and use `RelativeLayout` instead. It is support library bug, and has no solution upto this date. You can simply use following layout code for `ViewPager` along with `Toolbar` and `TabLayout`. `ViewPager` won't overflow in this case as it has been pointed out in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I have used Relative layout inside of CoordinatorLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the TabLayout outside the AppBarLayout.

Something like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary_blue_dark"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary_blue"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/primary_blue_light"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_layout_font_style"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"/>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Wrong answer, it works because view pager has no behavior

Answer (score 0):

For me the only sollution that worked with a Coordinator Layout, so that Viewpager layout_height stays within limits was adding **layout_behaviour** to the Toolbar, like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

Probably too late for you, but maybe it helps someone else.

This didn't bother me when I started my app, but later when I wanted to add a snackbar on another tab, the snackbar was only visible if I scrolled the page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

and setting

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tl_WelcomeTabs"
```

in the ViewPager's XML attributes. **0dp** in this case means something like **match_constraint**.

For example this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_WelcomeTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mission"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_welcomePager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tl_WelcomeTabs"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image] [image]

Left image: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` right image: `android:layout_height="0dp"`

**tldr;**

Change

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

and set `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` in the ViewPager's XML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Override behavior of your view pager wit, and add your view pager to this.layouts

```
override fun onDependentViewChanged(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: View, dependency: View): Boolean =
            super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency).also {
                layouts.forEach { it.setPadding(it.paddingLeft, it.paddingTop, it.paddingRight, it.top) }
            }
```