# Fragment's layout is too high with TabLayout + AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I'm struggled with this for hours looking for solution on google and stackoverflow. Thought that this is some trivial bug in my app but finally made empty project and can reproduce this too. Just run new project and select "Tabbed Activity" with navigation style "Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager)

Then try to put any widget at the bottom of the fragment's layout. I did this by modify fragment_main.xml and adding:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:textAlignment="center"
```

So the whole layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="aaaaaaa"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In design mode everything looks fine:
[image]

But when you run app:

[image]

You will see text only when you swipe action bar to hide it:

[image]

So it is impossible to set widget at the bottom of the tab's fragment or even match some list/picture to the height of the parent because bottom edge will be always under navigation bar.

Workaround which I found is here:
[ViewPager with Toolbar and TabLayout has wrong height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535695/viewpager-with-toolbar-and-tablayout-has-wrong-height)

First one is to put `AppBarLayout` and `ViewPager` between `LinearLayout` but then I lose hidding action bar functionality when scrolling ViewPager's content. Second one is add `android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` in `ViewPager` but then there is a gap when I hide action bar. Seriously there is no solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an expected behavior since the ActionBar gets hidden when scrolling up. In the design mode the text can be shown because it doesn't display the TabLayout. However, when you launch the app, it will inflate the TabLayout and the fragment will go below it. So it's not like the fragment is getting expanded or giving you wrong height.

Imagine putting an ImageView that has a matching height of the visible field (from below the TabLayout to right above the navigation menu). When you hide action bar from there, it will have a gap on the bottom since there's no content to fill up the space of hidden action bar, unless you stretch the ImageView as you scroll up, which will result in wired stretched image :/

One possible solution I can think of is, if you want to add a view on the bottom of the fragment, I will set the actionbar padding to the view and when I scroll the screen, I will adjust the padding depends on the scroll offset so that I can always be on the bottom.